# Can't run elixir interactive mode

Tags: elixir

I was following the guide to setup the Elixir on Ubuntu machine. But I got an issue when I tried to run the command. PFA. Can any help me to get the correct way? Please suggest me, if any other way to setup the same on Ubuntu.

```
./bin/iex
```

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Did you run `make clean compile` first? It looks like you just cloned the repo and ran the `iex` bash script, but that will fail because the Elixir .beam files have not been compiled yet. You can see hints of this in the errors which read `{reason, {undef, [{'Elixir.IEx.CLI', start, []}]}}`, which basically means that the module/function/argument combo of `Elixir.IEx.CLI.start()` is not defined, when it definitely would be in a successful installation.

Comment: Thank you @bitwalker. Actually I had problem with Erlang version. I installed <17 version in my system. Now, I updated the Erlang to latest. It's working now.

Comment: Right on, I'll have to remember that in case I see someone have that problem again. It's not at all clear that it's the wrong version of Erlang which caused it!